# Jmeter path setting in Http Request Sampler

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

**I have a website whose path variable is**

```
www.google.co.in/search?q=jmete+path+for+links+with+plus+sign
```

What do I write in the **path section** of **Http request sampler**

Answer (score 0):

You need to split [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to the following fields:

1. Server Name -www.google.co.in
2. Path - search (or /search)
3. Add Parameter in Parameters tab:

   A. Name: q

   B. Value: jmete+path+for+links+with+plus+sign

[image]
Another option is put full URL in Path

http://www.google.co.in/search?q=jmete+path+for+links+with+plus+sign

> As a special case, if the path starts with "http://" or "https://" then this is used as the full URL.

Comment: if I want to put the value:jmete+path+for+links+with+plus+sign in a csv file.How will I separate the + signs

Comment: @paulpo why you want to separate it?

Comment: take an example if I want to search products e.g-mobile+phones,samsung+tv.In csv file it will not look good if I input with + sign.In csv I want to input e.g-mobile phones,samsung tv.So,How will I add + sign later in script?

Comment: @ if you check `Encode?` check box it will convert spaces to `+` signs automatically